# How to save the player that has most kills in bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have the methods in the PlayerDeathEvent to save to separate yml files each of the followings:

*The player kills (everytime a player dies, it'll add a kill to the killer's file)

*The player deaths(same as above, but adding a death to the dead's file)

But I need a way to check all the files to search for the five top players to have the highest "Kills" value, and I think that checking every file each time a command is typed would be pretty heavy.

Is there a better way to check who are the players to have the highest "Kills"?

If there's a need to further clarify the question, please let me know!

Comment: Why not use a simple RDBS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that, is to create a new class, that will contain all the data of a player (player's UUID, his kills, etc.), and keep your player's stats saved in `config.yml` as a `List<PlayerKills>`, and keep it loaded when the server is running. Then, when needed, go through every instance of the list,  and gather the top 5 by their amount of kills.

Here is an example:

```
public class PlayerKills {
private UUID playerUUID;
private int kills;

public PlayerKills(UUID uuid) {
    this.playerUUID = uuid;
}
public void addkill() {
    this.kills++;
}
public int getKills() {
    return this.kills;
}
}
```

Another way, would be to use a MySQL database, and gather the top 5 players with a simple SQL query. That has an advantage of working across networks of servers, but disadvantage that it will require external plugins/libraries, and a MySQL database.

Comment: How do I save the full List<PlayerKills> ?

Comment: @Kerooker To write a List of a custom classes, you need to make PlayerKills class implement ConfigurationSerializable interface. For more information, read this: http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference#Serializing_and_Deserializing_Objects